# Can I set View.Tag to complex object DECLARATIVELY in layout xml?

Tags: android

1. I have layout composed by several other views (components).
2. The application have several modes and several steps
3. I need to achieve the following:
   Declare in layout xml which view is visible in which mode(s) and step(s).

First I implemented this in the following way:

```
<declare-styleable name="BaseLayout">
    <attr name="modes" format="flags">
        <flag name="none" value="0" />
        <flag name="simple" value="1" />
        <flag name="full" value="2" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="steps" format="flags">
        <flag name="none" value="0" />
        <flag name="params" value="1" />
        <flag name="base_results" value="2" />
        <flag name="detailed_results" value="4" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

In my components there is no problem to create custom app:xxxxx attributes and do what I need.
But I need the same for some whole layout (LinearLayout), not only for views in it. **So I hope there is a common solution.**

So I first created an override of LinearLayout and I used this instead of LinearLayout in my xmls to achieve what I need, **but I'm not sure this solution is fine**.

**So I wonder if I can use tag for this purpose.**
I've read in google that I can set complex object using setTag(....) but I prefer set these declarativly.

Best Regards

Comment: I see nothing wrong with overriding `LinearLayout` as you suggested you did in your question, I would think that's a good way to go

Comment: I found that it's possible to declare several <tag>s inside a view declaration:

    `<MyComponent
        android:id="@+id/unemploymentFundView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <tag android:id="@+id/modes"
            android:value="simple|full"/>
        <tag android:id="@+id/steps"
            android:value="detailed_results"/>
 </MyComponent1>`

If it's not possible to declare all in one <tag> then I'll use this option with several <tag>s.

(sorry about formating - I'm note sure how to format code in comment)

Comment: Unfortunately the variant with  multiple <tag id="xxxx">s is not a solution too. because this xxxx id should be unique in the layout file.
So for the moment I solved my problem by code.